# limit problems involving infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

find $$lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{20+2\sqrt{x}+3x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2+\sqrt{4x-3}+(8x-4)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
i confused on seeing the cube root.please give me a hint.Thanks

Comment: Divide both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x}$, and recall that $\sqrt{x} = x^{1/2}= x^{3/6}$ while $x^{1/3} = x^{2/6}$. You'll see what term(s) go to zero afterwards on both denominator and numerator, and which "remain" when $x\to \infty$.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is the largest power of $x$, top and bottom, so divide both by this.

Comment: @ Rene Schipperus is there any reason for dividing by$\sqrt(X)$

Comment: @Rene Schipperus thanks for your hints .i solve it.

Comment: @ClementC .thanks sir

Comment: the searched limit is $1$

Answer (score 0):

Generally,

> $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { a{ x }^{ m }+... }{ { b }{ x }^{ n }+... }  } =\begin{cases} +\infty ,\quad if\quad m>n\quad  \\ \frac { a }{ b } ,\quad if\quad m=n \\ 0,\quad \quad \quad if\quad m<n \end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you explain it. How?

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?